# Различие в словах на python

Tags: python, строки, python-2.x

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку оптимальный способ найти различия между двумя словами (слова отличаются только на один символ) на python. К примеру у нас есть два слова:

```
a = 'helloo'
b = 'hello'
```

Нужно найти:

1. Количество способов, которыми можно из слова с ошибкой удалением одного символа получить правильно еслово.
2. Если количество способов больше 0, то через пробел вывести позиции удаляемого символа для каждого способа в порядке возрастания. позиции нумеруются с 1.

Например:

1. входные данные:

```
a = 'helloo'
b = 'hello'
```

2. результат:

```
1) 2  
2) 5 6
```

```
a='helloo'
b='hello'
list_a = list(a)
list_b = list(b)
for item in list_b: 
    if item in list_a: 
        list_a.remove(item) 
    print(a.count(list_a[0])) d = 
    a.index(list_a[0]); print(d+1, d+2)
```

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникли затруднения? Задача досаточно простая. Алгоритмическая сложность `O(n)`, т.е. понадобится один проход по буквам первого слова.

Comment: Могу привести пример если вы приведете в вопросе попытку самостоятельного решения... На SO не принято помогать тем, кто не прилагает усилий и __не пытается__ решить задачу самостоятельно. Кроме того, если вы не сталкивались с Python, то как вам поможет готовый ответ / пример?

Comment: @Van можно из длинной выбрасывать по букве и сравнивать строки `(a[:i] + a[i+1:]) == b`

Comment: Данная задача легко решается одним циклом for. [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html) вы можете с ним ознакомиться. 
Если не получится то я скину готовый ответ, даю вам возможность научиться самому (:

Comment: a='helloo'
b='hello'

list_a = list(a)
list_b = list(b)

for item in list_b:
    if item in list_a:
        list_a.remove(item)

print(a.count(list_a[0]))
d = a.index(list_a[0]);
print(d+1, d+2)
Можно ли данную задачу решить проще?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774316/python-difflib-highlighting-differences-inline